# Print text if int value is greater than 0

Tags: c#, razor

I have a razor mergefield called: `@NumberChildren`. If `NumberChildren` has a value greater than 0, then I need to print out a text.

Table 1 below is working fine, and I only see this table if there is a number which is greater than 0.

Table 2 should print out the text, if `@NumberChildren` is greater than 0. But the text in table 2 always print out no matter if `@NumberChildren >= 0 =< 0`

Can anybody see why is this happening ?

```
<!-- Table 1: Print out how many children -->
@if (NumberChildren > 0)
{
<tr>
    <th width="300">
        <p class="text-left small-text-left"><strong>Number of children:</strong></p>
    </th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th width="300">
        <p class="text-left small-text-left">
            @NumberChildren
        </p>
    </th>
</tr>
}

<!-- Table 2: Print out text if there is children-->
@if (NumberChildren > 0)
{
    <tr>
        <th>
            <span>
                Payment are incuded for children under 10 years.
            </span>
        </th>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: I think that your two IF statements have other code (in your original code) in between that change the value of NumberChildren

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no table in html code provided in here, you might have a single table but you are generating only `tr` - table-rows in `c#` code. Did you mean if there is a problem with `tr` generating ? because I think you have all this code wrapped in a `<table>` tag and as the result `<table>` tag is always generated. If the situation is different please share some more info here.